# Test faild when I run one test

Tags: spring, junit, spring-data-jpa

Hello I have a problem whith spring data, I want to create test for my repository and I am using Junit
this is my class of test :

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
class TodoRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private TodoRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void should_store_a_todo() {
        Todo todo = new Todo(1L, "Learing TDD", true);
        Todo savedTodo = repository.save(todo);
        assertThat(savedTodo).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("id", 1L);
        assertThat(savedTodo).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("task", "Learing TDD");
        assertThat(savedTodo).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("completed", true);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_find_all_todos() {
        Todo tut1 = new Todo(1L,"Desc#1", false);
        entityManager.merge(tut1);
        Optional<Todo> todo = repository.findById(1L);
        Assertions.assertTrue(todo.isPresent(),"The todo 1L should be present");
        Todo tut2 = new Todo(2L, "Desc#2", true);
        entityManager.merge(tut2);
        Todo tut3 = new Todo( 3L,"Desc#3", false);
        entityManager.merge(tut3);
        Iterable<Todo> todos = repository.findAll();
        assertThat(todos).hasSize(3).contains(tut1, tut2, tut3);
    }
}
```

when I run the test of the class the test of te last function faild and when I run the test for the function it works.
when I debug the code, I see that in should_find_all_todos the object   Todo tut1 = new Todo(1L,"Desc#1", false); dosn't persist in the database, and after retrieve data using repo I found two objects tut2 and tut3

Comment: Can you try with removing @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) and see if your tests pass.

Comment: I am addign @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) for gettin new transaction but when I removet I get the same error

Comment: So you are saying that when you run the complete set of tests (Class) all of them pass but when you run only `should_find_all_todos` it fails. Is that it?

Comment: Is the oposite when I run the Class test the function faild , but I found the solution thanks